# How to force Apple Pay to work in the Safari session without quitting Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, apple-pay

I have a problem with Apple Pay occasionally. In some situations, Apple Pay does not load. The payment screen is just aborted instantly. Apple Pay on the Web Demo (https://applepaydemo.apple.com) lists the error as:

Apple Pay JS:

```
Payment cancelled by WebKit:

session.oncancel
```

Payment Request API:

```
PaymentRequest AbortError: The operation was aborted.
```

Interestingly enough, when I load up Safari Technology Preview and visit Apple Pay on the Web Demo it works completely fine. No errors. And also when I switch profiles from my administrator profile to my regular profile on MacOS, it works fine. There seems to be something wrong in the original Safari session and I can't figure out the fix for it.

I have tried Command + Q which fixes it. But I would like to know if there's a work around to that. I almost always use Private mode in Safari so figuring out a way to not need to Command + Q to fix this issue would be great (since Private does not save info from session to session).

Currently on MacOS Monterey Version 12.4, Macbook Air M1 2020, Safari Version 15.5