# Where is information for Safari Private stored?

Tags: safari, web-browsing, cookies, macos

I noticed an interesting case where a website had blocked me from accessing contents on Safari (Private Mode), switching over to Safari Technology Preview (Private Mode) resolved these issues. Either through a user-agent ban or stored cookies (which should be impossible since I'm on Private Mode), somehow regular Safari is not able to work.

Does anyone know why a unique situation like this could occur? I'm wondering if it's because of cookies/identifiers stored somewhere inside my MacOS files causing the website to allow me to use it at all. I understand that using Safari Private does not allow cookies to "exist" after it shuts down. Even after rebooting my Macbook, clearing all Safari data, and emptying my caches, the website is still blocking me. However, using Safari Technology Preview fixes everything. Does Safari PT interact differently with websites? Is Safari Private actually keeping identifiable information even after closing out of it? Surely **some** information from Safari Private is stored somewhere, either deep in the files/folders of /Library or in RAM, which is why Safari TP works and Safari Regular does not.

Weird situation, hoping someone can help me out.

Comment: Is the site [still Apple Pay Demo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/443325/5472)

Comment: Actually I figured out why Apple Pay Demo itself didn't work already. It had to do with PaymentUIExtension Safari Process.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because Safari Technology Preview is a different version of Safari and has improved handling of Private Mode detection, or as you said – a user agent ban.